# How do I put a Ruby function into a SQLite3 query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, sqlite

I have a function which I need to put into a SQLite3 query.

I have the following method:

```
def levenshtein(a, b)
  case
    when a.empty? then b.length
    when b.empty? then a.length
    else [(a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : 1) + levenshtein(a[1..-1], b[1..-1]),
      1 + levenshtein(a[1..-1], b),
      1 + levenshtein(a, b[1..-1])].min
  end
end
```

and I want to do a query that looks something like this:

```
@results = The_db.where('levenshtein("name", ?) < 3', '#{userinput}')
```

What I want to find the values of name in `The_db` where the edit distance between the value of the name column and the user input is less than `3`. The problem is that I don't know how to use a Ruby function in a query. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [`create_function` method](http://rdoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database#create_function-instance_method). You can use it to create a custom function like this (where you have already defined your `levenshtein` Ruby method):

```
db.create_function "levenshtein", 2 do |func, a, b|
  func.result = levenshtein(a, b)
end
```

You can then use it in your SQL:

```
# first set up some data
db.execute 'create table names (name varchar(30))'
%w{Sam Ian Matt John Albert}.each do |n|
  db.execute 'insert into names values (?)', n
end

#Then use the custom function
puts db.execute('select * from names where levenshtein(name, ?) < 3', 'Jan')
```

In this example the output is

```
Sam
Ian
John
```

I haven’t tested this in Rails, but I think it should work, the query string is just passed through to the database. You can get the Sqlite `db` object using [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter.html#method-i-raw_connection). (I don’t know how to configure Rails so that all ActiveRecord connections have the function defined however – it does seem to work if you add the function in the controller, but that isn’t ideal).

Having shown how this *can* be done, I’m not sure if it *should* be done in a web app. You probably don’t want to use Sqlite in production. Perhaps it could be useful if you’re using e.g. Postgres with its own `levenshtein` function in production (as suggested in [the Tin Man’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939629/214790)), but want to use Sqlite in development.

Comment: Actually, it's because the levenshtein function takes too long... This means you answered my question. Thanks! If you know another way to test similarity between two strings, let me know :D

Comment: Developing with a different DBM than in production is OK, but not really recommended, because there can be differences in the SQL implementation that will leak back into the code; We write code to accommodate the database, which then causes problems after pushing to production against a different DBM. Considering that PostgreSQL is free and fits nicely into almost any machine a developer would use, it's hard to justify not using it during development. Yeah, there's a little overhead for setting it up, but once that's done it's very transparent.

Comment: @matt Could you comment on why SQLite is not suited for production?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the value of a column to insert it into a Ruby function, then you have to retrieve that value first.

The DBM can't call your method in your running code; You have to have the value, pass it to your method, then use the result in a secondary query.

Or use a DBM that has a [Levenshtein function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) built in, like PostgreSQL or define it in pure SQL.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: I think you can figure that part out. Do a select to get the needed field from the right record, compute the distance, then do your next search.

Comment: Does this mean that i have to iterate through all the values in the name column?

Comment: It sounds like you need to follow the advice in the final paragraph. In a big database (which you shouldn't be storing in SQLite), retrieving every value for a column, then processing them in Ruby, would be bad system design. A good DBM has a full SQL implementation, and that will make it possible to write a function or stored-procedure, which executes in the DBM to process your Levenshtein code, and return the results for you.

Comment: In embedded databases like SQLite, calling back into the user code is trivial.