# rails math query inside where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am using ROR with SQlite3 and I am trying to get results from locations table which satisfy a math condition containing square terms of attributes. "locations" table contains Latitude:float and Longitude:float Field. 
Here's my line of code for search :

```
@results = Location.where('Latitude > ? AND Latitude < ? AND Elevation > ? AND Elevation < ? AND ((Latitude-?)**2 +(Longitude - ?)**2 <= (?)**2)',@latitude_Range_Start,@latitude_Range_End,@elevation_Range_Start, @elevation_Range_End,@latitude_mycity.to_f, @longitude_mycity.to_f, @rad_range.to_f)
```

Rails is displaying this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE (Latitude > 20.7333148 AND Latitude < 40.7333148 AND Elevation > -651.3542785644531 AND Elevation < 1348.6457214355469 AND ((Latitude-30.7333148)**2 + 
        (Longitude - 76.7794179)**2 <= (1111.0)**2))
```

How do I query my condition in where clause. It seems that squaring the terms inside it is the problem. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have a `**` operator.

Unless you have [created a user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939574/how-do-i-put-a-ruby-function-into-a-sqlite3-query), you have to compute the squares manually:

```
...where('Latitude  BETWEEN ? AND ?  AND
          Elevation BETWEEN ? AND ?  AND
          (Latitude  - ?) * (Latitude  - ?) +
          (Longitude - ?) * (Longitude - ?) <= ? * ?', ...
```

(Please note that this formula assumes that the earth is flat.)

Answer (score 0):

According to this post:

[How to find power of a number in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite)

SQLite doesn't have a power / exponential math function.

You'll need to do as much math as possible in Ruby and pass in raw comparison values.